# Any way to encode the url in curl command?

Tags: curl, url

I have some url which has space in it's query param. I want to use this in curl,
e.g.

```
curl -G "http://localhost:30001/data?zip=47401&utc_begin=2013-8-1 00:00:00&utc_end=2013-8-2 00:00:00&country_code=USA"
```

which gives out

```
Malformed Request-Line
```

As per my understanding o/p is due to the space present in query param.

Is there any away to encode the url automatically before providing it to curl command?

Answer (score 253):

`curl` supports url-encoding internally with `--data-urlencode`:

```
$ curl -G -v "http://localhost:30001/data" --data-urlencode "msg=hello world" --data-urlencode "msg2=hello world2"
```

`-G` is also necessary to append the data to the URL.

*Trace headers*

```
> GET /data?msg=hello%20world&msg2=hello%20world2 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
```

Comment: What if  `msg = '='` ?

Comment: From curl doc: Note that the name part (msg in this case) is expected to be URL-encoded already. Also you can specify something like --request DELETE and it would indeed be a delete method instead of a GET. Not sure if order matters.

Comment: @damphat what happens when the request has two parameters like `"msg1=Hello&msg2=World"`? This will encode the `&` between the parameters which would mean wrong thing to send to the server

Comment: @GaneshSatpute: use multiple `--data-urlencode` parameters, one for each key-value pair.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. that works. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa just repeat the `--data-urlencode` option, like in the example provided

Comment: Is it possible to perform query params url-encoding for a POST request **and** provide a payload ?

Comment: i wonder why this answer is not accepted.

Comment: Is it possible to do urlencode on part of the url, instead of the data? I.e. to access `localhost:123/hello%20world`.

Answer (score 5):

```
 curl -G "$( echo "$URL" | sed 's/ /%20/g' )"
```

Where `$URL` is the url you want to do the translations on.

There are also more than one type of translation (encoding) you can have in a URL, so you may want to do:

```
curl -G "$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape shift, , q{^A-Za-z0-9\-._~/:}' -- "$URL")"
```

instead.

Comment: Note that `echo "$URL" | sed 's/ /%20/'` won't do the right thing if there are `%` characters in the URL. Also, spaces are normally encoded as `+` (and `+` as `%2b`). I recommend the Perl solution, which is reliable.

Comment: `sed 's/ /%20/g'` if you have more than one space to translate...

Comment: Note I had to install the Perl URI::Escape module.